# python assignment of complex objects

Tags: python

I have following code which works fine. but the minute I remove comment across statement print `list(B)` it fails and returns as an empty list. I'm thinking perhaps X is getting address location of `list(B)` executed as part of print statement.

```
import itertools
A = [1,2,3]
B = itertools.product(A,repeat=2)
print str(B)
#print list(B)
X = list(B)
print X
<itertools.product object at 0x7f5ac40a9a50>
[(1, 1), (1, 2), (1, 3), (2, 1), (2, 2), (2, 3), (3, 1), (3, 2), (3, 3)]
Command took 0.03s
```

Answer (score 5):

`B` is an *iterator*. If you ask for `list(B)` then you will *exhaust the iterator*, causing it to be empty the next time you do `list(B)`.

As a rule-of-thumb: when dealing with iterators, you rarely need to assign them to names. Usually, you either just iterate over the iterator with `for-in`, or you use `list` to convert the iterator into a list.

Answer (score 1):

[`itertools.product`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.product) returns an iterator, so when you do `print list(B)` it has already iterated through all the products and then if you retry `list(B)` , B would not have anything , so `list(B)` would return empty list.

You can just try printing `list(B)` 2 times to see the same result -

```
>>> B = itertools.product(A,repeat=2)
>>> print list(B)
[(1, 1), (1, 2), (1, 3), (2, 1), (2, 2), (2, 3), (3, 1), (3, 2), (3, 3)]
>>> print list(B)
[]
```